# Why is read to memory three times slower than read to /dev/null?

Tags: file, ubuntu, io, nfs

I would like to read files fast from my disk, I have tried three methods:

1. bash: cat file_path > /dev/null
2. d:    auto data = read(file_path);
3. bash: rsync -av -P file_path path_to_fast_file_system

Method 1. reads at 470MB/s, which is ok speed wise, but the files end up in /dev/null which is not suitable for my needs.
Method 2. and 3. read at 140MB/s which is slow, but they do what I need.

Why is it three times slower to read into memory than to read into /dev/null?
Please let me know how I can read the data of a file at the same speed as cat to /dev/null but into memory or through rsync?

Comment: Dear anonymous down voter, thanks for evaluating my question, however please let me know how I can improve my question as I am genuinely interested in a solution to my issue.

Comment: I have investigated this issue for some month, I have written various programs and monitored a handful of different disk systems and servers with a number of different tools and use cases, all systems are professional grade well maintained hardware with up to 100TB disk, 10Gb network and 256GB memory systems. For the questions I have tried to simplify it down to something manageable that illustrates the issue thereby perhaps giving the falls impression that no research has gone into the question.

Comment: If I may suggest, /dev/null is fastest because it actually does nothing. When writing to hard drive (if this is what you call "memory"), it is normal because the hardware takes time to move electrons and stuff around.    \\ Which speed do you expect from your hard drive vendor?

Comment: My harddisk vendor sais that the disk system can fill the 10Gb connection, so I seem to get only about half of that, but my main issue is the drop in speed when I actually want to do something with the data. I have tried to write a small C program that just reads blocks in to memory, and it seems it is the memory part that slows it down, I just always thought that copying bytes in memory was much faster than the 140MB/s I observe.